# R strsplit is too slow

Tags: r, string

Raw data is like this:
      `modelinputparameter=c("2644971410,35,0,0,65,0.5645161290322581,0,34,0,24,0,59,0,49,526,62,74,100,0,2,74,101,0.06653992395437262,0.0,0.0,0.12357414448669202,0.5384615384615384,0.0,0.0,0.5483870967741935,0.0,0.0,0.3870967741935484,0.0,0.0,0.01773049645390071,0.041666666666666664,1.1935483870967742,0.0,0.0,0.14068441064638784,0.74,1.1935483870967742,0.14068441064638784,0.7326732673267327,0.42957136,0.012157798,0.56455743,0.027011633,0.46380696,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1,1,1,0,2,1,FirstDay,3,3,-1,-1,16,1,5,1,HTL,5,9,5,9,5,0,23")`

My code is the following:

```
parameter_HTL <- strsplit(filter(rawdata,hotelbelongto!='SHT')$modelinputparameter, ',')
rawbetalog_HTL <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,parameter_HTL),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

while rawdata has 5 million rows, so it takes a while to split the data and combine them to d DataFrame. Is there any code to do the same work ?

The final result is like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `strsplit`? It has a `fixed` argument you can make use of here

Comment: modelinputparameter is one of rawdata's columns.rawdata is a DataFrame.